# Please explain Long equality condition

Tags: java, wrapper

Consider the following conditions:

```
if (isCustom() == new Long(1)) {
    System.out.println("ok 1");
}
if (1L == new Long(1)) {
    System.out.println("ok 2");
}
```

For the following definition:

```
static Long isCustom() {
    return 1L;
}
```

Output is:

> ok 2

But for

```
static long isCustom() {
    return 1L;
}
```

Output is:

> ok 1
>
> ok 2

I am not getting the point here!

Comment: **Very** bad naming to have `isCustom()` return a Long. The name implies a boolean return value.

Comment: Yes, but it depends on how you are using it, and general conventions certainly sometimes do not apply. It was a test code though. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Generally speaking, `foo == new Anything()` is always false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the former case, you're returning an Object that was autoboxed.

In the latter case, you're returning a long value.

Because the latter is just a value, the code is evaluating equivalency of the *values* 1L and [the autounboxed value of an object with the value] 1L.

In the former case, the code is evaluating the equivalency of the *identities of two objects* that both have the value 1L.

Comment: Oops...I just missed that == and equals discrimination! Brainjam!!

Answer (score 3):

In the first case you have two `Long` objects, and you are checking if they are the same object (because you are using `==`, not `.equals`). They are not the same object.

In the second case you have a `long` value being compared to a `Long` object, and the `Long` gets unboxed into a `long` value. `==` works fine for `long` values.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, your `isCustom()` method is returning a `Long` -- the `1L` is boxed to a `Long` object.  When you use the `==` operator on it, Java uses reference equality.  Those two `Long` objects, even though they represent the same `long` -- `1L` -- are different objects, so the condition is `false` and `"ok 1"` is not printed.  Note that [certain `Long`s are not required to be cached like certain `Integer`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf-long-).

> Note that unlike the corresponding method in the `Integer` class, this method is *not* required to cache values within a particular range.

In the second example, your `isCustom()` method is returning a `long` -- no boxing is performed here.  The `==` operator then unboxes the `Long(1)` to `1L` to compare it to the `long` returned by `isCustom()`, the condition is `true`, and `"ok 1"` is printed.

Answer (score 1):

This is all to do with java primitives and boxed types.  The primitive version `long` gets automatically converted by java ("boxed") to the object version - `Long`, and vice versa for "unboxing".

In the first scenario above, you're returning a boxed primitive `Long` (i.e. an object), and comparing to see if the object has the same reference as a new object you've just created.  In other words you're comparing a `Long` with another `Long`.  Since you created a `new Long()`, the objects are different, so the if statement returns false and "ok 1" is not printed.

In the second scenario, you're returning the primitive type, and comparing a primitive with an object - i.e. a `long` with a `Long`.  In this case, the object (`Long`) gets "unboxed" to a primitive type, and when comparing two primitive types with `==`, you're not checking the object reference but rather you're checking to see if they have the same value.

The second case ("ok 2") is always comparing a primitive `long` with an object `Long`, and so is always true for the same reasons as the second scenario above.